# Format cell to number type "Percentage"

Tags: excel, format, applescript

I am trying to format the range *"C3:C8"* in Microsoft Excel to the number format Percentage. The below code does not work and I am unsure why. After running the script the range *"C3:C8"* remains formatted as *"General"*.

I am using Excel for Max 2011 and Applescript Editor Version 2.7

```
set formatRange to range "C3:C8" of sheet "Sheet1"

set number format of (formatRange of (sheet "Sheet1" of active workbook)) to "Percentage"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
front document activate
set formatRange to range "C3:C8" of sheet "Sheet1" of active workbook
set number format of formatRange to "###.00%"
end tell
```

cell value 1 will be converted to 100.00% and cell value 0.02 will become 2.00%
Of course, you can change the string "###.00%" with "###.0%" if you only want 1 decimal digit.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a solution...or at least a workaround for the time being

set value of range "C3:C8" to "0%" --this will automatically set the format to percentage

set value of range "C3:C8" to " " --this will now set the value of each cell to blank, but leaves the format as percentage